# How to remotely log in and call an API?

Tags: php

Let's abstract away the difficulties of the world and suppose that this fellow here has currently one HTML page with two forms in his arsenal. They look like this:

```
 <form method="POST" action="foobar.com/login"> ...
 <form method="POST" action="foobar.com/getstuff"> ...
```

The first logs in a remote server, setting cookies and so on, and the second one sends a request to that server to show data.

How can I accomplish this task in PHP, logging in and fetching the data in a single page load?

Comment: What kind of control do you have control on foobar.com?

Comment: Not much, it's in another subdomain. I can make requests to its programmer, yet I cannot change software nor server configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You can use cURL for the communication, server side. Technically your server would be logging in to the remote server. So if you need many sessions connected, it might work as long as the remote server does not limit the number or sessions per IP address.

More info in: http://php.net/curl

Answer (score -1):

Your questions is not that clear to me, but let's try:

The easiest way would be that the response of the server to the first form sent is the second form.

Or you could work with frames (which I would not advice).

Another possibility would be that you send the forms with ajax in the background. There are a lot of js frameworks that allow an easy usage of ajax (jquery, prototype, ...).

Comment: Ajax, dear friend, is precisely what I'm trying to avoid, since I'm in a different domain and would get CORS issues. I also cannot implement on the server-side the pre-flight workarounds.